# How does Apache flink distribute data among nodes?

Tags: apache-flink

I have setup a 2 node standalone Apache Flink cluster. For small amount of data (70 MB), the parallelism of 2 takes more time (2 min 30 seconds ) to process where as the parallelism of 1 takes just 18 seconds. How is the overhead more for small amount of data and why is it insignificant in case of large amounts of data?.I want to know more details about the distribution of data in case of large and small data and characterize the performance. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the parallel execution of an Apache Flink application slower than the sequential execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986523/why-is-the-parallel-execution-of-an-apache-flink-application-slower-than-the-seq)

Comment: I want to know in detail how to characterize the performance in case of both small and large data with parallelism. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there's an exact answer for the things that you are asking. I'm gonna try to explain myself the best i can, but i'm not an expert in the field.

1) How is the overhead more for small amount of data and why is it insignificant in case of large amounts of data?

The overhead is insignificant in big amounts of data, because a single node can't handle all the data and if the node can't handle all the data, there are two thing that can happen:

1. You drop data and you loose it
2. The node generates backpresure in your system and that could be a huge problem if it isn't managed.

So, if you have multiple nodes processing all the incoming data, you can process that data as soon as it arrives, the data isn't waiting for a node to process it. That's why the overhead is insignificant.

2) I want to know more details about the distribution of data in case of large and small data and characterize the performance.

The distribution of data it's very difficult to explain, because it depends a lot of what are you doing and the config of your system. Read the following docs:

1. [Flink runtime](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/concepts/runtime.html)
2. [Flink Rescalable state](https://flink.apache.org/features/2017/07/04/flink-rescalable-state.html)
3. [Flink parallelism](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/parallel.html)

The way you config your system and your aproach to design a job will influence how the data is partitioned and distributed.